# Why can't I use the laptop mouse or keyboard in any X window manager on an Alpine Linux machine?

Tags: linux, xorg, input-device

My laptop's keyboard and mice don't work in an X session anymore regardless if started by xinit or a dm.  The keyboard works fine in a tty though. I would've included all the necessary info in my first two drafts, but it kept getting marked as spam, here's everything related to xf86

```
libxxf86vm-1.1.4-r2
libxxf86vm-dev-1.1.4-r2
xf86-input-evdev-2.10.6-r1
xf86-input-libinput-1.2.1-r0
xf86-input-mtrack-0.5.0_git20220223-r0
xf86-input-synaptics-1.9.1-r3
xf86-video-intel-2.99.917_git20210115-r1
```

the laptop is an HP 8440p with integratd intel graphics

I can use an external keyboard and mouse if I start X with a dm and plug the peripherals after starting lightdm as the keyboard wouldn't work if it was pluged in while loading the dm.

The issue is with udev, I think, as in my Xorg.0.log the only relevant line before an xf86EnableIO error is about udev, and Alpine doesn't come with udev rules.

Comment: You should add hardware specifications, namely graphics and whether or not you have proprietary drivers installed and which version, etc. Please [edit] accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked worked, while all other suggestions on the internet did not:

```bash
apk add udev xf86-input-libinput

rc-update add udev-trigger boot
rc-update add udev-settle boot
rc-update add udev-postmount boot

reboot
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can confirm this worked on fresh install of Alpine 3.18.

Comment: Now we have bots spewing "not enough information" nonsense. This answer makes 100% sense and solved my mouse/kb issues. Thank you.